# C string split problem

Tags: c, string

I am writing small IRC Bot, and i need to split incoming messages for easier handling. I wrote a function `get_word`, which should split string. According to gdb and valgrind, problem is that function sometimes returns invalid pointer, and program fails when trying to free that pointer.
Here is the code:

```
char **get_word(char *str) {
   char **res;
   char *token, *copy;
   int size = 1;
   for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
      if(str[i] == ' ') {
         while(str[i] == ' ') {
            i++;
         }
         size++;
      }
   }
   res = malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(char *));
   copy = strdup(str);
   token = strtok(copy, " ");
   for(int i = 0; token != NULL; i++) {
      res[i] = strdup(token);
      token = strtok(NULL, " ");
   }
   free(copy);
   res[size] = NULL;
   return res;
}
```

Comment: C has a wonderful feature where you can code `/*` and some words and then `*/`.  If you insert these "comments" into your code at various points it makes it far easier for you to understand what you're doing, and also makes it easier for other people.

Comment: Shouldn't you also be returning the number of words?

Comment: @misha no, because `res` is `NULL` terminated

Comment: Could `str` ever end with a space?

Comment: Please put the valgrind log. It may help us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem I see is with your nested loops:

Consider this input: `' \0'`

The function execution reaches the `for` loop, `i == 0`. Then the `while` loop is also entered. At the end of `while` loop `i == 1`. Now the incrementation statement from the `for` loop is executed and `i == 2`. So next you will be reading past the end of the string.

**EDIT**

I understand that `size` is the number of words found in the input. So I'd go for something like:

```
for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    if (str[i] != ' ' && (str[i + 1] == ' ' || str[i + 1] == '\0')) {
         // Counting endings of words
         size++;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your suggestion? I guess i should use something like `while(str[i+1] == ' ')` insted ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **split (const char *str)
{
char **arr = NULL;
size_t cnt=0;
size_t pos, len;

arr = malloc (sizeof *arr);
for (pos = 0; str[pos]; pos += len) {
    char *dup;
    len = strspn(str+pos, " \t\r\n" );
    if (len) continue;

    len = strcspn(str+pos, " \t\r\n" );
    if (!len) break;

    arr = realloc (arr, (2+cnt) * sizeof *arr);
    dup = malloc (1+len);
    memcpy (dup, str+pos, len);
    dup [len] = 0;
    arr [cnt++] = dup;
    }
arr[cnt] = NULL;
return arr;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char **zzz;

for( zzz = split( argv[1] ); *zzz; zzz++) {
    printf( "->%s\n", *zzz );
    }
return 0;
}
```

The reallocation is a bit clumsy (like in the OP) and improving it is left as an exercise to the reader 8-}

Comment: Well that's not helpful at all. using `realloc()` so many times is just too slow. I already wrote something like this some time ago, and it was even shorter, but that's not what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: As I said: it is suboptimal (clumsy) but correct. BTW: your "size" variable counts the number of characters, not words. That is also suboptimal :-)

Comment: No, size does count number of words. It is increased every time when 1 or more adjacent spaces are found. :)

Comment: Does it handle tabs, too? But: on second thought: yuo're righ. My method could simply be augmented by introducing a preloop to  count the number of words (+ the sum of their sizes); just like yours does. But it still is correct; even in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

As julkiewicz points out, your nested loops where you count the words could miss the terminating null on str.  Additionally, if `str` ends with spaces, your current code would count an extra word.

You could replace this section:

```
int size = 1;
for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
   if(str[i] == ' ') {
      while(str[i] == ' ') {
         i++;
      }
      size++;
   }
}
```

..with something like this:

```
while (*str == ' ') str++;  // skip leading spaces on str
/* count words */
int size = 0;
char *s = str;
do {
  if (*s && *s != ' ') {
    size++;                       // non-space group found
    while (*s && *s != ' ') s++;  // skip to next space
  }
  while (*s == ' ') s++;          // skip spaces after words
} while (*s);
```

..which counts the starts of groups of non-space characters, rather than groups of spaces, and watches for the terminating null in the inner loops.

You might also consider changing:

```
for(int i = 0; token != NULL; i++) {
```

..to:

```
for(int i = 0; token && i < size; i++) {
```

..just as a slightly paranoid guard in case `strtok` finds more words than you counted (though it shouldn't).

Answer (score -2):

I think gdb may be complaining about the fact that you never check the return value of `malloc` (or `strdup`) to see if it's non-NULL.

Comment: -1: this doesn't really qualify as a useful answer - gdb doesn't care whether you check return values or not