# Removing a specific part of a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

How can I remove, in C, a part of a string? I am interested especially in a built-in function, or an efficient code to do it.
I have this line of code:

```
char namefile[256] = "/Users/student/Desktop/Silviu/g7.08e11.01024"
```

and I want to keep only "g7.08e11.01024" so I can use it somewhere else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C string split problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546647/c-string-split-problem)

Comment: Please tell more about the condition to splice. You can use `strstr` or `strchr` to get the address of character and use it.

Comment: If you're asking a C question don't tag it as C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `strrchr`:

```
const char* shortName = strrchr(namefile, '/') + 1;
```

`strrchr` returns the address of the last occurence of `/` in the string.

Comment: Thank you this was the solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the following way

```
char namefile[256] = "/Users/student/Desktop/Silviu/g7.08e11.01024";
char *p = strrchr( namefile, '/' );
if ( p )
{
    for ( char *q = namefile; *q++ = *++p; );
}
```